# Folders for movies / image sequence

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to set different folders for images (which where saved from animation renders) and for movies (which are the result of video editing)
For me it looks like there is just one output folder.

I personally think it is a lot of work if you want to make movies from image sequences you need these steps (especially if you have different output folders)

0. change your output to /images
1. render animation (which outputs the files to e.g. /images)
2. new -> Video editing -> add -> and then search for your images and add them
3. change your output file to your e.g. /movie - folder
4. render

I hope i am just to dumb to find a better alternative...!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're struggling with. You can use the compositor and its file output node, if that answers your question. Also I'd suggest use davinci resolve instead of the VSE.

Comment: thx, did not know that ...just a beginner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set more output directories in Compositor editor.

- **For a movie** set output directory and format in *Properties editor > Output Properties*
- **For an image sequence** use *Compositor editor* > **File Output** node

[image]

See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/file.html

Comment: If you are looking for an option to later merge image sequence into movie you can use some external script in terminal. Under OS X I was able to manage a Quick Action that lets me select images (or folder) in Finder and with right click to use an action. There are additional installations needed like FFMPEG and ImageMagic, but ones it is done it is supper easy, but that is topic other sites, not here.